# Hужны ли кавычки после двоеточия?

Tags: пунктуация

1) Таким образом, физическая география отвечает на вопрос: "Где и какая природа?", объясняет особенности и разнообразие природы в разных местах.
2) Также физическая география отвечает на вопросы: Как правильно использовать блага природы? Как сделать так, чтобы ей не навредить?

Answer (score 1):

При оформлении подобных предложений могут использоваться различные варианты в зависимости от их структуры и содержания, например:

1) Таким образом, физическая география отвечает на вопрос, ***где и какая природа***, объясняет особенности и разнообразие природы в разных местах. Это косвенная речь, придаточное изъяснительное предложение.

2) Также физическая география отвечает на следующие вопросы: **Как правильно использовать блага природы? Как сделать так, чтобы ей не навредить?**

Пример:

*Методика преподавания математики призвана дать ответы на следующие три вопроса: Зачем надо учить математике? Что надо изучать? Как надо обучать математике?*https://studbooks.net/1915878/pedagogika/osnovnye_zadachi_metodiki_prepodavaniya_matematiki

Comment: Ну вот, а Вы говорите править смело. Тут вроде явно надо было поправить. Вообще не понимаю, зачем пробел и почему "так же" раздельно. Или Вы просто правили одновременно со мной, а не не согласились с моей правкой? :)

Comment: Да, наверное, одновременно, так как там появилась какая-то странная надпись. "Также" я вроде бы копировала, не понимаю, откуда взялось раздельное написание. Поэтому оформление, пожалуйста, правьте. Спасибо.

Comment: Всё правильно: у автора было раздельно, я у него тоже поправил после Вашего ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Да, я бы поставил кавычки, потому что слово "вопрос" походит на вводное, указательное: ...**отвечает на вопрос: "где и какая**... (и не с прописной, а со строчной, потому что это не прямая речь).

Comment: Каким правилом объясните? Есть ли правило, ссылка на пример?

Comment: Какие правила, если они: 1) не озвучены; 2) даже если озвучены, то изменяются под напором авторитетного мнения? В этой области (кавычки) никто правил не решается выкладывать, тут только чутьё. Я сам по себе, плюю на авторитетов, давно пора понять это. Матрицу разрушит точность.

Comment: Поддержу использование двоеточия указанием на то, что это начало прямой речи — вопрос «Где и какая природа?» можно полноценно озвучить, а потому мы его не менее полноценно цитируем. *Пишу сюда, так как вопрос заблокирован.* // сс @Нижегородец